How to automatically create PV, VG,LV, format,mount filesystem after I attach data disk to rhel Linux azure VM via python
Based on Microsoft document I am able to create and attach data disk to RHEL azure virtual machine, I can append a data disk to my Linux Azure VMs and initialize the disk manually by login to the VM. Everything works for me.
BUT it is not enough as I want to make the whole process automatically by code. Could you please give me some code sample or guide about it? Thanks!

To automatically create PV, VG,LV, format,mount filesystem after you attach data disk to Linux VM on azure via python you can use below script using paramiko
import paramiko


HOST = "123.456.789.105" #updatewith ur own VM details
USERNAME = "arko"
PASSWORD = "Madhuri@123"
VG_NAME = "vg_data_new"  
LV_NAME = "lv_data_new"  
MOUNT_POINT = "/mnt/data_new"  

commands = [
    "echo y | sudo pvcreate -ff /dev/sdb",  
    f"sudo vgcreate {VG_NAME} /dev/sdb",
    f"sudo lvcreate -y -l 100%FREE -n {LV_NAME} {VG_NAME}",
    f"sudo mkfs.ext4 -F /dev/{VG_NAME}/{LV_NAME}",
    f"sudo mkdir -p {MOUNT_POINT}",
    f"sudo mount /dev/{VG_NAME}/{LV_NAME} {MOUNT_POINT}",
    f"echo '/dev/{VG_NAME}/{LV_NAME} {MOUNT_POINT} ext4 defaults 0 0' | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab"
]

def execute_commands(commands):
    print("Debug: Starting command execution on /dev/sdb with new volume group and logical volume names")
    try:
        
        client = paramiko.SSHClient()
        client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        client.connect(HOST, username=USERNAME, password=PASSWORD)
        
        
        for command in commands:
            print(f"Executing: {command}")
            stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(command)
            output = stdout.read().decode()
            error = stderr.read().decode()
            if output:
                print(f"Output: {output}")
            if error:
                print(f"Error: {error}")
        
        print("Disk setup completed successfully with new names.")
        
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
    finally:
        client.close()


execute_commands(commands)



You can verify the same by logging into the VM and do a lsblk

